# Java Reflect newInstance() causing a ConcurrentModificationException (CME) resulting in a crash

Tags: java, methods, reflection, crash, concurrentmodification

To sum up my project I'm trying to make an event processor that runs methods from a given list of methods. In order to invoke these methods I need to pass in the newInstance of the method. The method is correctly run, however, right after the whole program crashes with a "ConcurrentModificationException".

```
@EventHandler
private Listener<EventKeyInput> eventKeyInput = new Listener<>(event ->
{
    for(Method m : event.getMethods())
    {
        try {
            m.invoke(m.getDeclaringClass().newInstance(), event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

One of the methods I wish to call

```
@EventAnnotation()
public void eventKeyInputeTest(EventKeyInput event)
{
    System.out.println("EventKeyInput test!");
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide anymore code. Thank you for any help!

Edit: Added the class where I change the method

Is there any other way to go about this?

```
for(Method m : listenable.getClass().getMethods())
    {
        if(m.isAnnotationPresent(EventAnnotation.class))
        {
            Parameter[] params = m.getParameters();
            if(params.length != 1)
            {
                System.out.println("You need 1 event paramter!");
            }
            
            Class<?> eventType= params[0].getType();
            
            try {
                Object methods = eventType.getMethod("getMethods").invoke(eventType.newInstance(), null);
                Method add = List.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class);
                add.invoke(methods, m);
                eventType.getMethod("setMethods", ArrayList.class).invoke(eventType.newInstance(), methods);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Apparently, at least one of the methods you invoke reflectively modifies the collection of the event. It’s a strange design anyway, that the event provides a collection of `Method` objects, the listener invokes on an ephemeral instance, without caring about their purpose. Since even the `m.getDeclaringClass()` stems from the `Method` object provided by the event, the event ultimately decided which concrete method to invoke, but the purpose of this Reflection indirection is not clear.